# Expectation and variance of an equation with a varaible that follows a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given that $d$ follows an equation, $d= (v^2/g)\sin2\theta$, in which v and g are constants and $\theta$ follows a uniform distribution on $[\pi/6, \pi/3]$, try to find the expected value and the variance of $d$.

I had the idea of directly integrating d, but I guess the uniform distribution of theta does have an effect and I should also be considering that, but I'm not really sure how to factor that in. The answer is $(3v^2)/(\pi g)$ for the expected value. It would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction... Thank you so much!

Comment: Given $\theta \sim [a,b]$ is a [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution), then $\mathsf{E}[\theta] = \frac1{b-a} $  and $\mathsf{Var}[\theta] = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12} $.

Comment: @GohP.iHan Thank you! It turns out that while I did try to use E[θ], I seemed to have used the wrong formula for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x)f(x)dx$$

$$\mathbb{E}[g(\theta)]=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{v^2}{g}sin(2\theta)\frac{6}{\pi}d\theta=\dots=\frac{3v^2}{g\pi}$$

Use similar arguments for the variance, remembering that

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

Comment: Oh! I did attempt that but I got a little stuck. Would f(x) be θ here? Does it matter that the θ follows a normal distribution on [π/6, π/3] (and how should I use this info? I tried setting the limits of the integration to π/6, π/3, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track) Thank you!

Comment: @Ren : edited with more details. $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{6}{\pi}$

Comment: Thank you so much!!